# How can i find indices of element that bigger than special number from numpy 2d array?

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, indexing, find

I want to find index of element that bigger than 2  from numpy 2d array.

like this

```
import numpy as np
a = np.array([[1,2,3],[4,5,6]])

#  find indices of element that bigger than 2
# result  = [[0,2],[[1,0],[1,1],[1,2]]
```

Comment: I want solution that not use double for loop

Comment: ```zip(*np.where(a > 2))``` - https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.where.html`... ```np.argwhere(a>2)``` - https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.argwhere.html#numpy.argwhere

Comment: Thanks! I will have to try this.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `np.where()` which will gives you the expected indices in a tuple mode (separate axis):

```
In [6]: np.where(a>2)
Out[6]: (array([0, 1, 1, 1]), array([2, 0, 1, 2]))
```

Or directly the `np.argwhere()`:

```
In [5]: np.argwhere(a>2)
Out[5]: 
array([[0, 2],
       [1, 0],
       [1, 1],
       [1, 2]])
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer!